# How to take array size and elements' inputs from a text file in java?

Tags: java, arrays, file, input, java.util.scanner

This is for an online judge (Codeforces). Input file is like this

**input.txt**

> 6
>
> 4 3 2 1 5 6

First line is the array size and second line contains the array elements.

I've tried it by using this

```
 public static int readFiles(String file){
        try{

        File f = new File(file);
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(f);
        int n = Sc.nextInt();
        return n;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return 0;
    }
}
public static int[] readFiles(String file,int n){
    try{

        File f = new File(file);
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(f);
        Sc.nextInt();
        int arr [] = new int [n];
        for(int count = 0;count < n; count++){
            arr[count] = Sc.nextInt();
        }
        return arr;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}

public static void main (String args [] ){
        int n = readFiles("input.txt");
        int arr [] = readFiles("input.txt",n);
```

Comment: You was near to the solution, but there is no need to do it by two methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the method that builds the array without provide `n`:

```
public static void main (String args [] ){
    int arr [] = readFiles("input.txt");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    int n = arr.length;
    System.out.println("n is: " + n);
}

public static int[] readFiles(String file){
    try{
        File f = new File(file);
        Scanner Sc = new Scanner(f);
        int n= Sc.nextInt();
        int arr [] = new int [n];
        for(int count = 0;count < n; count++){
            arr[count] = Sc.nextInt();
        }
        return arr;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("The exception is: " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

if you need `n`, you can get it by this line `arr.length`.

Comment: okay I did it. It improves the code but still the code doesn't work

Comment: could you post your output or the exception? why does not  work?

Comment: The problem is it doesn't show any stack trace on anything. Just says wrong answer. And my code doesn't give any output in the OJ. The output is blank

Comment: Ok, may be you get an exception (may be file not found exception).. I update the answer to get more info about it.

Answer (score 0):

your code will never work because is not even compiling

if this method `readFiles(String file)` return an int then it makes no sense doing this

```
int arr [] = readFiles("input.txt",n);
```

## hint:

1. read the file line by line,
2. check if spaces are there
3. get the numbers as string
4. parse those into integers
5. put them in the array
6. return at the end that array.

Comment: Is there any simpler way of doing this? Using some other methods or anything?

Comment: It works in my own compiler. But when I submit it to the OJ, it doesn't return any output

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this on your for loop to split the numbers between empty spaces and store it in an array :

```
int temp[] = Scanner.readLine().split(" ");
```

Comment: And then I'll convert the string array into an interger array?
how to do that?

Comment: Ohh my bad.It should be integers.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a bufferedreader to read the lines one at a time, like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numberArray = readFile();
}

public static int[] readFile(){
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))) {
        int arraySize = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String[] arrayContent = br.readLine().split(" ");
        int[] newArray = new int[arraySize];

        for(int i = 0; i<arraySize; i++){
            newArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(arrayContent[i]);
        }
        return newArray;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: File: E:\CodeForces\PhysicsPractical.java  [line: 70]
Error: Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7

when I try to compile it says this

Comment: You dont have Java 1.8 or 1.7 on your computer?

Comment: You can move the bufferedreader out of the try statement then like this:

Comment: try { BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"))